# Node Express variable in jade called several times

Tags: node.js, express, pug

When I render the page I have several variables

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
Posts
  .findOne({category:"homepage"})
  .populate({path:"image"})
  .exec(function(err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    return res.render('index', {
      title: post.title,
      _header: {test:"test"},
      post: post
    });
  });
});
```

Then, on my jade template I output the "_header" variable like this:

```
div
    -console.log(_header.test)
div
```

I then get the variable output, but it gets called again undefined, several times.

```
Cannot read property 'test' of undefined
```

Has anyone been faced to this?
I've been working with express for several years, first time I see this.

Comment: how about to do `res.locals._header = {test: "test"};` before `res.render()` ?

Comment: it seems like You've another route where You render same file or same partial file that cannot get `_header` that is not provided.